# How to subscribe cache events in thin client

Tags: ignite

I use thin client to communicate with Ignite node, right now, I can read from Cache, and write to Cache. But I want to get the Cache event real-time, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that thin client has this functionality. You will need to use client node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, Client node has this feature, but we'd like to refactor our client application to use thin client instead. Not sure thin client has an alternative.

Comment: @AresZhu Functionality that requires pushing updates from server to client will very unlikely ever be supported by thin clients. This includes any type of listeners, near caches, etc. These clients are more suitable for operations that do not require to be part of the cluster - you should be able to connect, execute and disconnect.

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko thanks, it seems that if thin client wants to get the updates from server, it has to join the cluster.

Comment: Yes, but it will not be a thin client anymore though :)

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko Yes, we'd like to keep thin client, since we do not want our client to be much heavy, but we need the function getting updates from server, is there any suggestions on this?

Comment: You will have to choose one or another. This is a tradeoff.

Comment: Apache Ignite is actually not that heavy. It's a single jar.

Comment: @AresZhu I agree with others in this thread. Why do you think that thin client is heavy? It is actually very light weight. The only difference is that it joins the cluster in the client mode and supports the full Ignite API, including transactions, events, etc. Thin client is much more limited in functionality and is really meant for cases when joining the cluster is not an option.

Comment: @Dmitriy, sorry, might not saying clearly, I mean to keep thin client which is pretty light weight, but the functions are limited, we cannot use events. Right now our platform is based on ignite cluster which we are thinking a little bit heavy, so we plan to refactor it to use thin client instead.

Comment: @alamar Thanks, our client is written in C#, not want java involved.

Comment: You could deploy continuous query as e.g. Java service, talk to it through thin client.

Comment: @AresZhu I am not sure I understand. The thick client is very light weight and should not be a problem. However, now it seems that you do not want to install Java because you are using .NET. The thin client in .NET will have less features than thick client. May I ask why is Java installation such a big issue? You should never even see it or notice it from your application.

Comment: @alamar Thanks, if so, that should work, but how to talk with the service through thin client? My understanding is thin client can only operate caches.

Comment: You can use REST's execute command to talk to java task which will talk to service which has continuous query deployed. https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#execute